# Simple Perl program to print the time to nano resolution to screen

Tags: linux, perl, bash

If I run Date +%H:%M:%S.%N from a  linux bash  command-line it prints out the time to nanosecond resolution. I am trying to continuously print that to the screen but this perl program doesn't seem to work. What I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


while(1)

{
        print system("Date +%H:%M:%S.%N");
}
```

Comment: For one thing, your filesystem is case-sensitive and the command is `date`, not `Date`.

Comment: just.. be more simple! `do{}while 1 `

Comment: @loldop: How is that simpler?

Comment: Don't call an external program.  Use the `Time::HiRes` module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DateTime::HiRes?](https://metacpan.org/module/JHOBLITT/DateTime-HiRes-0.01/lib/DateTime/HiRes.pod)

```
c:\Code>perl -MDateTime::HiRes -E "while (1) {say DateTime::HiRes->now()->strftime('%F %T.%N');}"
2013-05-23 18:53:32.220020000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.220460000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.220800000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.221080000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.221350000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.221640000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.221950000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.222260000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.222570000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.222880000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.223190000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.223490000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.223810000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.224120000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.224430000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.224750000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.225070000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.225390000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.225710000
2013-05-23 18:53:32.226030000
```

...

Comment: It would be my preferred implementation rather than invoking the painfully expensive `system` call, but it's only 'accurate' to the microsecond

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that what he was looking for was 'better than second' resolution rather than true nanosecond resolution. I'm not sure perl's the right language for real nanosecond-level work.

Answer (score 2):

> If I run Date +%H:%M:%S.%N from a linux bash command-line it prints out the time to nanosecond resolution.

Perhaps you have a function, alias, or non-standard command called `Date`.  The name of the standard command is `date` (command names are case-sensitive). If you have something called `Date` that works from your shell prompt, it likely won't work from a Perl script.

And your Perl script prints the value returned by the `system` function, which is an integer containing information about the status of the command.

This should work (*without* the `print`).

```
system("date +%H:%M:%S.%N");
```

This is better, since it invokes `date` directly without going through the shell:

```
system('date', '+%H:%M:%S.%N');
```

`perldoc -f system` for more information on the difference.

But this still has the overhead of invoking an external command. With a little more work, you can do this in pure Perl. There are several CPAN modules that manipulate dates and times.

Even so, keep in mind that a nanosecond resolution timestamp isn't going to be entirely meaningful; your systems' clock isn't *that* accurate, and the call to determine the time is likely to take at least several nanoseconds.

Comment: does he also need `$| = 1`?

Comment: @Petesh: Probably not, but it couldn't hurt. If the output is redirected to a file, it might be buffered, causing lines not to be physically written immediately; `$| = 1` turns off that buffering.